# Nginx add a response header that describe the upstream server used

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm starting to use nginx with multiple backends by using the `upstream` directive. I want nginx to add a response header that describe which backend server was used to serve this request. Something like this would do:

```
X-Backend-Server: localhost:8000
```

I've configured `ip_hash` as the load balancing mechanism.

Is there any way to configure nginx to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I haven't thought of that! Thanks you @MichaelHampton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up setting the header in the backend server (as @MichaelHampton suggested), so nginx forwards this request to the client. As I am using grails, I've added a filter to add the response header (based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415452/grails-add-header-to-every-response)

```
import javax.servlet.*
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class AddLocalHostnameToResponseFilter implements Filter {

    static final logger = LogFactory.getLog(this)
    String hostname

    void init(FilterConfig config) {
        try {
            this.hostname = InetAddress.localHost.hostName ?: 'unknown'
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error", e)
            this.hostname = 'unknown'
        }
    }

    void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        response.setHeader('X-Backend', this.hostname)
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    void destroy() {
    }
}
```

And adding this to the `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>addLocalHostnameToResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>AddLocalHostnameToResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>addLocalHostnameToResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hm , what?!?! your question was about NGINX, (with tags nginx;load-balancing;) , not about third party application, so you asked about one thing, and proposed an answer for a totally different one...you have to change the meaning of your question!

Comment: Hi @ADM. Someone suggested me that I could set the header from the backend. I used that idea and posted the answer for reference. Thanks!